# How to use Jina templating by using Ansible inventory membership and variables in a for each statement

Tags: ansible

What i'm trying to accomplish:

I want to use Jinja templating to fill in a single line (*see below*) depending on Ansible Inventory Groupmembership & variables.

By using the files descibed below i'm trying to accomplish that when the **current host** is member of **group 1** it should fill **config.xml** with **ansible_variable_1**. Or when the **current host** is member of **group 2** it should fill **ansible_variable_2**. Etc...

Jinja template config.xml.j2:

```
<activedFilters userFilter="(&amp;(sAMAccountName=%v)(objectcategory=user)(|(ansible_variable_1/2/3)))"/>
```

I've tried using `{% if inventory_hostname in groups['group 1']  %} {{ ansible_variable_1 }} {% elif inventory_hostname in groups['group 2']  %} {{ ansible_variable_2 }} {% endif %}` But I don't want to 'hardcode' the group names, i'd like to use a for each statement(?) to match the right group to the right variable.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Group_vars:

```
ansible_variable_1: 
ansible_variable_2:
ansible_variable_3:
```

Ansible inventory:

```
[group 1]
Server1.hostname.com

[group 2]
Server2.hostname.com

[group 3]
Server3.hostname.com
```

Comment: if you will not use group names then how would you know that which variable to define ? because having a loop over all the groups and then matching if it the current host is a part of group is easily possible but then how will you decide that if i need to define variable 1 2 or 3 ? please clarify a bit

Comment: Hi TechMaster, you are correct that you wont be able to decide the right variable. The example of Techraf fixes this issue. In my case i fixed it by defining the unique vars in group_var

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why you want to make your life harder. Ansible gives you the mechanism of group variables, so use it:

```
[group1]
Server1.hostname.com

[group2]
Server2.hostname.com

[group3]
Server3.hostname.com

[group1:vars]
ansible_variable=value1

[group2:vars]
ansible_variable=value2

[group3:vars]
ansible_variable=value3
```

And in template:

```
<activedFilters userFilter="(&amp;(sAMAccountName=%v)(objectcategory=user)(|({{ ansible_variable }})))"/>
```

<sup>or whatever you want your output to look like.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for you reaction Techraf. We'd like to keep the iventory as clean as possible and use the group_vars where possible. Is this not the way to go in this case?

Answer (score 0):

if you want a loop over solution, it should be like:

```
{% for gname in groups -%}
{% for host in groups[gname] %}
{% if hostvars[host].ansible_host == ansible_host %}
## now you got your current host
## here you can do some conditions or variable defining
{% endif %}
{%- endfor %}
{%- endfor %}
```